# EnumResourceNames Function C++

Tags: c++, winapi

So I try to read resource types and names from given file (in my case, .msstyle on my desktop) using C++

But somehow the resinfo result is sort of weird and not accurate. It doesnt write what actually was found. For example, the msstyle gives a result of: http://pastebin.com/ZhnkPmUe

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <stdio.h>

HANDLE g_hFile;
BOOL EnumTypesFunc(HMODULE hModule, LPTSTR lpType, LONG lParam);  
BOOL EnumNamesFunc(HMODULE hModule, LPCTSTR lpType, LPTSTR lpName, LONG lParam);  
BOOL EnumLangsFunc(HMODULE hModule, LPCTSTR lpType, LPCTSTR lpName, WORD wLang, LONG lParam);

void main(void)
{
    HMODULE hExe; 
    TCHAR szBuffer[80];
    DWORD cbWritten; 
    size_t cbString;
    HRESULT hResult;

// Load the .EXE whose resources you want to list.
    hExe = LoadLibrary(TEXT("C:\\Users\\Kala\\Desktop\\776.msstyles"));
    g_hFile = CreateFile(TEXT("C:\\Users\\Kala\\Desktop\\resinfo.txt"), GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, (LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES) NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, (HANDLE) NULL);  

// Find all of the loaded file's resources.
    hResult = StringCchPrintf(szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer)/sizeof(TCHAR),TEXT("The file contains the following resources:\r\n\r\n"));
    hResult = StringCchLength(szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer)/sizeof(TCHAR), &cbString);

    WriteFile(g_hFile, szBuffer, (DWORD) cbString, &cbWritten, NULL); 
//Calls the function to find types
    EnumResourceTypes(hExe, (ENUMRESTYPEPROC)EnumTypesFunc, 0);                             
// Unload the executable file whose resources were
    FreeLibrary(hExe);
    CloseHandle(g_hFile);
}
//    FUNCTION: EnumTypesFunc(HANDLE, LPSTR, LONG)
//
//    PURPOSE:  Resource type callback
BOOL EnumTypesFunc(HMODULE hModule,  LPTSTR lpType, LONG lParam)
{
    TCHAR szBuffer[80];  // print buffer for info file
    DWORD cbWritten;     // number of bytes written to resource info file
    size_t cbString;
    HRESULT hResult;

    // Write the resource type to a resource information file.
    // The type may be a string or an unsigned decimal
    // integer, so test before printing.
    if (!IS_INTRESOURCE(lpType))
    {
        hResult = StringCchPrintf(szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer)/sizeof(TCHAR), TEXT("Type: %s\r\n"), lpType);
    }
    else
    {
        hResult = StringCchPrintf(szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer)/sizeof(TCHAR), TEXT("Type: %u\r\n"), (USHORT)lpType);
    }

    hResult = StringCchLength(szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer)/sizeof(TCHAR), &cbString);
    WriteFile(g_hFile, szBuffer, (DWORD) cbString, &cbWritten, NULL);
    // Find the names of all resources of type lpType.
    EnumResourceNames(hModule, lpType, (ENUMRESNAMEPROC)EnumNamesFunc, 0);

    return TRUE;
}

//    FUNCTION: EnumNamesFunc(HANDLE, LPSTR, LPSTR, LONG)
//
//    PURPOSE:  Resource name callback
BOOL EnumNamesFunc(HMODULE hModule, LPCTSTR lpType, LPTSTR lpName, LONG lParam)
{
    TCHAR szBuffer[80];  // print buffer for info file
    DWORD cbWritten;     // number of bytes written to resource info file
    size_t cbString;
    HRESULT hResult;

    // Write the resource name to a resource information file.
    // The name may be a string or an unsigned decimal
    // integer, so test before printing.
    if (!IS_INTRESOURCE(lpName))
    {
        hResult = StringCchPrintf(szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer)/sizeof(TCHAR), TEXT("\tName: %s\r\n"), lpName);
    }
    else
    {
        hResult = StringCchPrintf(szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer)/sizeof(TCHAR), TEXT("\tName: %u\r\n"), (USHORT)lpName);
    }

    hResult = StringCchLength(szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer)/sizeof(TCHAR), &cbString);   
    WriteFile(g_hFile, szBuffer, (DWORD) cbString, &cbWritten, NULL);
    return TRUE;
}
```

I think I must be missing something because I dont seem to get a proper strings I wanted from it, so if anyone could point me to right direction I would be very thankful

Comment: Those are _wide_ strings

Comment: What's your system? It might be localization issues...

Comment: Windows 8 and C++ 2010 express if you mean that
Wide strings? How can I convert these to readable strings then?

Comment: Windows has been a Unicode operating system for 20 years already.  Resistance is futile.  Project + Properties, General, change the Character Set property to "Use Unicode Character Set".

Comment: It is alraedy set to Use Unicode. Although if I set it to "Use Multi-Byte Character Set" it works.
Anyway to fix it to use Unicode?

Comment: _"result is sort of weird and not accurate"_ Explain what you expect and what you get instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file is UTF-16 encoded because you are using the Unicode version of the Win32 API. Your text editor is interpreting the file as being 8 bit encoded. So you simply need to get your text editor to interpret the file as UTF-16. Probably the easiest way to do that is to put the UTF-16LE BOM at the beginning of the file.

As an aside I would advise you to stop coding to support MBCS character sets, stop using `TCHAR` and so on. Just write your program assuming that you will be targeting the Unicode version of the Win32 API. It will make your code much easier to read if you write `L"..."` rather than `TEXT("...")` and so on. Of course, if you need to support Windows 9x then forget I said this and carry on writing code that will compile in both MBCS and Unicode modes.

Comment: Assumptions are a poor foundation to base code upon. Consequently your advice to drop **half** of the MBCS support and hope that the other half will miraculously fall into place is bad. If you absolutely must suggest to drop `TCHAR`s you also have the responsibility to promote using the Unicode versions of the Windows API explicitly by appending an appropriate `W` suffix. Or simply live with the fact, that some of use still have to support MBCS and move on.

Comment: @Tim If you still have to support MBCS then clearly it's different. That seems unlikely here. A lot of people do it because they are following patterns of other people doing so. Once you decide to stop supporting MBCS, why would you need to specify the `W` suffix explicitly? The header file macros add it. That just makes your code even less readable. Your perspective is obviously very different if you still have to support Win9x. If you don't need to then it all looks different.

Comment: _"[Supporting MBCS] seems unlikely here."_ This question and the answers are meant to be useful to future visitors as well. You are not just answering **this** question, but also questions that have not even been asked. _"Why would you need to specify the `W` suffix explicitly?"_ Because your choice of data type promises that you will **always** be using the Unicode version, regardless of preprocessor definitions. Being explicit is part of our job.

Comment: @Tim That's a pretty high standard you want to hold me to. I've got to write completely general advice that covers all possible scenarios. I think that's unrealistic. It was an aside. I've added a rider now. I think I answered the question that was asked.

Comment: You make it sound like I'm asking for more when I'm really asking for less. The aside was voicing an opinion rather than answering a question and it was uncalled for. I'm not questioning your answer. It is the incomplete advice I feel is problematic.

Comment: @Tim Advice can be ignored. But perhaps this is a viewpoint that would be better expressed in a comment.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648037(v=vs.85).aspx  found this sample code here, which im using, im sort of beginner in C++. No really need to support  Windows 9x but unicode support may be better. Not sure what to edit to get it support unicode

Comment: So, have I answered your question?

Comment: I get the point and answer too but im still bit of clueless to go on from here

Comment: You just need to write a UTF-16 LE BOM to the file right at the beginning. That's the bytes `FF` `FE` in that order. Read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: How about writing resources to disk instead of tree to text file, would ofstream work for that?

Comment: Don't know. Maybe. Not sure what your goals are. I just tried to answer the question that you asked.